# How to get the parent action in the inline action?

Tags: action, inline-action

There's a contract A with action 
`void a(string memo)`, it calls an inline action for contract B with action `void b()`, can I get the `"memo"` parameter in the function `void b()`?

Note that I can't modify the contract A, and you can assume that b is like a transfer action.

Comment: Not an answer, but in case the answer is "no way": If contract B and its function `void b()` are both under your control, you can at least copy the parameter on call, rewriting the function as `void b(string memo)`.